# Increase amount of a variable in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm currently working on a car counting project. I'm stuck with counting cars by substracting previous detected car value from the current one. I've tried memory block as previous detected car value. However, it does not count cars properly. It returns 0, sometimes 1,255,254.

Edit: After uint8 block, detected car number as 8 bit unsigned integer goes through.

[image: Simulink image]

Comment: You haven't asked a question.  Nor have you told us why you think the dimension of the signal being probed represents the number of cars.

Comment: Memory block holds just the previous sample for one sample time after one sample time both the top block and the bottom block will have the same value because the the delayed number also becomes the same assuming no car passes between one sample ,probably that is the reason it giving you zero  ... A delay block also does the same